# Creating a Transparent Checkbox with Background on Top

Tags: html, css, checkbox, background-image

I have a checkbox that I want replaced with an image. I'm able to successfully have the image overlap the checkbox. The problem is that the image has a transparent background thus causing the user to still see the checkbox. Is there any way I can make the actual checkbox invisible while I still maintain the image background.

CSS

```
input[type=checkbox]:before { 
  content:""; 
  display:inline-block; 
  width:12px; 
  height:12px; 
  background-image: url('http://www.jpl.nasa.gov/spaceimages/images/mediumsize/PIA17011_ip.jpg'); 
  background-size: 12px; 
}
```

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chk1" />
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hqZt6/713/).

Comment: something you expect like this http://jsfiddle.net/hqZt6/714/ if not explain me with some more detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Corrected.....

I added this `background-color: #fff !important;` to make the 'button box' invisible, or white, either way this replaces the button box display. (don't know why, but if you don't add `content: "";` it doesn't work :/)

Comment: I still need it to act as a checkbox so that option is not viable. Sorry :(.

Comment: updated. you can still see the check when it's checked, because I didn't kown if you want an image or just leave it; you said the image is transparent so can be either......